# Does iOS 6 support Core Image filters?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-image

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html) iOS 6 supports Core Image filters. But I remember that there was confusion about it before iOS 7, where Core Image was mentioned but then was not actually implemented in iOS.

Comment: iOS 6 do support Core Image filters and I am using it in my app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. Not all filters are supported, those that are are mentioned as such in the [core image filter reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html).